# plotting POSIXct values in R

Tags: r, datetime, plot, time-series

Im trying to plot datetimes of customer visits using a histogram but for some reason my plots are producing scientific notation for the y axis. My code is as follows:

```
hist(tsData, breaks = "months", plot = TRUE, freq = FALSE,
     start.on.monday = TRUE, format)

hist(tsData, breaks = "hours", plot = TRUE, freq = FALSE,
     start.on.monday = TRUE, format)
```

Which produce the following plots respectively,

[image: plot 1]

[image: plot 2]

My POSIXct values are in the format: "2018-03-13 10:18:14" for every visit. Am I plotting these date times incorrectly?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Would just a histogram work? Or use `cut()` and make a `barplot()`?

Comment: `options(scipen = 999)`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, I cannot tell for certain, but your horizontal axes seem to suggest you are plotting the date-times correctly.

As for your vertical axis, it is showing scientific notation because the density values are very small. In your first plot, `1.0e-08` is the same as `0.00000001`. It may be that the `format` you are passing to `hist` is setting the y-axis to scientific notation. Regardless, neither `1.0e-08` nor `0.00000001` are very readable. Since the probability densities are so small, your histograms may be more intelligible if you set `freq = TRUE` to show the counts.